# Adivinar numero en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Buenas tengo un programa que tiene que adivinar el numero que le introduzco en un TextField y tiene el usuario 9 intentos para ello. Si no lo adivina muestra por pantalla si el numero introducido es mayor o menor que el insertado y me dice los intentos que me quedan.

El problema es que me ejecuta todos los intentos en uno,es decir,introduzco un numero y me ejecuta todos los intentos cuando deberia ejecutarse solamente uno. El problema está en la función lambda del botón, no se como puedo realizar el bucle.

Espero que alguno pueda ayudarme, un saludo.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ejAdivinarNumero extends Application {

  static final int INTENTOS_MAXIMOS = 10;
  private TextField campoNumero=new TextField();
  int intentosQueQuedan;
  private TextArea area=new TextArea();
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage escenario) throws Exception {
    escenario.setTitle("Adivinar el numero");
    Scene escena=crearEscena();
    escenario.setScene(escena);
    escenario.show();
  }
  private Scene crearEscena() {
    Label label=new Label("Adivina un numero 1-100: ");
    
    HBox cajaHorizontal=new HBox(label,campoNumero);
    
    Button calcular=new Button("Intentalo...");
    cajaHorizontal.setSpacing(10);
    cajaHorizontal.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    VBox CajaVertical=new VBox(cajaHorizontal,area,calcular);
    CajaVertical.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    Scene escena=new Scene(CajaVertical,400,300);
    
    calcular.setOnAction(n->validarNumero());
    
    return escena;
  }

  private boolean validarNumero() {
    try {
      int n=Integer.parseInt(campoNumero.getText());
      int numSecreto = (int) (Math.random()*100 + 1);
      
        for (intentosQueQuedan=INTENTOS_MAXIMOS-1 ; numSecreto!=n && intentosQueQuedan>0; 
            intentosQueQuedan--) {
         if (n < numSecreto) {
           area.appendText("\nEs menor que el numero a adivinar");
         } else {
           area.appendText("\nEs mayor que el numero a adivinar");
         }
         area.appendText("\nTe quedan "+intentosQueQuedan+" intentos");
         campoNumero.clear();
        }
        
      if (numSecreto==n) {
        area.appendText("\nLo adivinastes");
        return true;
      } else {
        area.appendText("\nNo lo adivinastes, el numero es "+numSecreto);
        return false;
      }
      
    }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      area.appendText("\nNo es un numero");
      campoNumero.clear();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo que tendrás que hacer es que no haya bucle, sino que la variable que guarda los intentos esté a nivel de la clase y el botón, cuando lo pulsas, comprueba cuantos lleva y resta uno cada vez que pulses. Si ha llegado al máximo, o el botón muestra un mensaje, o de deshabilita o lo que quieras.

Comment: No deberías usar un bucle. Simplemente ejecutá el método cada vez que presionen el botón hasta que se cumpla alguna de las condiciones.